# Issue with ember-cli-rails and puma-dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, puma-dev

Just getting started with a rails api and ember frontend. I'm using ember-cli-rails and puma-dev. I'm getting an error when visiting the localhost at .test. I'm not sure what is causing it, or if it's due to both the front and back end bring set to "/".

Any point in the right direction would be appreciated!

NoMethodError
undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #19):

```
  def action_encoding_template(action) # :nodoc:
    *if @_parameter_encodings.has_key?(action.to_s)*
      @_parameter_encodings[action.to_s]
    end
  end
```

https://github.com/wjacobs71086/keenmind

Comment: where does `@_parameter_encodings` come from?

Comment: I'm guessing it's from a node_module since it's not in the main code base.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if I change config > routes.rb to a new path, then when viewing the"/" path, I see the default rails page and no error. Then viewing the new path I get the error. This seems to indicate that the issue is the ember build and not the rails API.

Comment: Can you trace the error? JavaScript and node modules have no direct impact on ruby code / gems, so i'm curious what is going on, and when the ruby code is looking for and not getting.

Comment: It's been a long while for me since using ruby, but have you followed all the steps in the README here? https://github.com/thoughtbot/ember-cli-rails

Comment: I followed the steps and did what I could to compare what I had to the example project they have listed. I may try again today without using puma-dev.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your repository out and I was able to (partially) fix it… Change the following:

```
- class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
+ class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```